# How to run custom code saved as string in database in the .ejs file

Tags: node.js, ejs

I have a String stored in database as site setting to run snippet/pixel code. So i want my code to have html/css/js/ejs code inside of it and be able to run in ejs file.

So i have something like this

```
var code= "
<% if(settings.snippet_pixel != ''){ %>
<script src="www.shareasale.com/xxxx" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
USI_orderID = '<%= order.uri %>';
USI_orderAmt = '<%= order.total.subtotal.toFixed(2) %>';
USI_currency = 'USD';
var USI_headID = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
var USI_dynScript = document.createElement("script");
USI_dynScript.setAttribute('type','text/javascript');
USI_dynScript.src = 'https://www.upsellit.com/active/<%= settings.upsellit_id %>_pixel.jsp';
USI_headID.appendChild(USI_dynScript);
</script>
<% } %>
"
```

So i want this code string to be editable for future edits so i dont have to hard code the ejs file. But i dont know how to pass it to the ejs file that i'm using as a partial on all pages(in the header)

Answer (score 0):

First thing, you should use ` in your string declaration instead of " otherwise your code will throw an error because the string will end before www.
Here is the correct example:

```js
var code= `
<% if(settings.snippet_pixel != ''){ %>
<script src="www.shareasale.com/xxxx" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
USI_orderID = '<%= order.uri %>';
USI_orderAmt = '<%= order.total.subtotal.toFixed(2) %>';
USI_currency = 'USD';
var USI_headID = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
var USI_dynScript = document.createElement("script");
USI_dynScript.setAttribute('type','text/javascript');
USI_dynScript.src = 'https://www.upsellit.com/active/<%= settings.upsellit_id %>_pixel.jsp';
USI_headID.appendChild(USI_dynScript);
</script>
<% } %>
`
```

Now, to add this string to your ejs you can append the code variable to it.

```js
await fs.appendFile('example.ejs', code, function (err) {
  if (err) console.log(err);
  console.log("It works");
});
```

- Dont forget to add the fs package and do `const fs = require('fs');` at the start of your code

Comment: i'm using node 7.0.0 await is not supported can you tell me how to work this out with promises?

Comment: There is a sync version of fs append file: `fs.appendFileSync('example.ejs', code)`

Comment: If you want I can help you with moving to a newer version of node.js, if you wanna dm on discord. Using a newer version can help you a lot with async/await, bug fixes, more compatible modules.

Comment: var fs = require('fs');
var snippet_pixel_code = '`' + result.allpages_upsellit_snippet_pixel + '`';
fs.appendFileSync('share_a_sale_upsellit_all_pages.ejs', snippet_pixel_code);

In the setting i passed <script>
alert('dajger');
<\/script>; and not showing

Comment: i cant upgrade it its not my project